# How can I use an if statement to move files that contain certain XMP data found by using exiftool

Tags: python, exiftool, xmp

I have located files that contain certain XMP data using Exiftool. How can i move those files if the argument meets the parameters.

Here is my code

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
filesPath = '/folderpath'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filesPath):
    for name in files:
        print("echo", os.path.join(root, name))
        subprocess.call(['exiftool', '-Route','-Final_image_in_location', os.path.join(root, name)])


        if Route = 4 and Final_image_in_location = 1: 
            print ("i got one")
```

Currently the if statement doesn't work

Comment: While I have no experience with Python, I don't see in your code that you're saving the exiftool output from `subprocess.call` and then parsing that output to fill your `Route` variable.  You might want to look into [pyExiftool](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/), which is a python wrapper for exiftool.  Your code loops and calls exiftool once for each file. Exiftool's biggest performance hit is it's startup time (see [Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3)) and if you're processing a lot of files, it could take much longer than needed.  PyExiftool avoids this.

Comment: Okay thankyou i have just stumbled across pyExiftool, looking into it now